# How to check if a glob pattern returns anything

Tags: shell-script, find, wildcards

How to check if `/var/some-dir/*` returns anything?

I use `find /var/some-dir/* ...` but if the pattern is empty I get an error. I don't want to redirect `stderr`.

I want to check before executing `find` is the pattern will return anything or an error

Comment: Are you asking "How do I avoid running a command, if a glob (the star thing) returns nothing?"

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to process the return value.

If `find` when used in this way finds nothing, it returns `1`, so you can do

```bash
find /var/some-dir/*
if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]
then
  perform_failure_action
fi
```

**If you want to check that beforehand**, you can try the following:

```bash
shopt -s nullglob
f=/var/some-dir/*
if [ -z $f ]
then
  printf -- "No such file!\n"
else
   find /var/some-dir/*
fi
```

The `shopt` line will ensure that if no file matches a glob pattern, it will expand to an empty string, which can then be tested via `-z`.

In this case, be sure *not* to quote the `$f` as you *want* glob expansion in that test. For the same reason, you must use the single-bracket test operator, *not* the double-bracket operator, which may implement its own "protection" scheme for the variable under test.

**Alternatively**, if you use a shell the supports it (e.g. Bash), you could use the `compgen` builtin command with the `-G` option. This will generate a list of completions of the glob pattern (`-G`) supplied to it and will return `true` if a match exists:

```bash
if compgen -G /var/some-dir/*
then
  find /var/some-dir/*
else
  printf -- "No such file!\n"
fi
```