# How to list matching files to a glob pattern?

Tags: scripting, find, ls, wildcards

I've read, and tried, various answers to a question similar to this but they don't work (or at least I can't get them to) for my particular use case.

I have a CI build pipeline that allows a glob pattern to be specified to publish multiple files.  The pattern is something like 'dir/subdir/**/*.ext'.  What I want to do is output the list of files that match this pattern, before publishing those files.

I've tried:

```
find . -path 'dir/subdir/**/*.ext'
ls 'dir/subdir/**/*.ext'
```

And several permutations, all seem to return a similar result.

The `find` above returns nothing, as a side note if I run `find . -path '**/*.ext'` it returns

```
./dir/subdir/debug/file1.ext
./dir/subdir/debug/file2.ext
./dir/subdir/publish/file1.ext
```

The `ls` command returns `ls: cannot access 'dir/subdir/**/*.ext': No such file or directory`

Is there a way for me to get the list of matching files before processing them, if so, how?

**Additional Clarification:**
The reason I want to get the list of files, is I want to fail the CI step if no files match the pattern.

Comment: Really this depends on what actually does the globbing: the programming language/library used by your CI system may handle this differently from ksh, bash, zsh and indeed some other programming language/library as well, especially when it comes to some corner case. With bash you can do something like `shopt -s globstar; printf %s\\n dir/subdir/**/*.ext`, but again, there's no guarantee that your CI system will process exactly those files.

Comment: @muru that really should be an answer

Comment: @muru The CI pipeline is running in a docker image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0` and the shell is bash.

Comment: Ah, but the docker container isn't the one interpreting this pattern though, is it? It's whatever executes the container that will use the pattern.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is the docker container that is interpreting it, the command is running inside the docker container.  If I run this from a PowerShell (Docker Desktop) container it works the way I would expect in bash, I don't think PowerShell understands globbing like that.

Answer (score 0):

@muru 's comment was correct, except I forgot to add an additional detail to my question, which was that I want an empty list if no files match (so that I can fail the script).

With this additional context the way I achieved this was

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob; printf %s\\n dir/subdir/**/*.ext
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630267/597281) for additional nullglob.